# Strange waterfall lag

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am really curious, why is there a blank space in my waterfall? It looks like everything is cached, but there is still some mystical 100ms lag between html and css.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser needs to parse you html file. It could take some time.

You can try to check the problem in Timeline panel.
It provides the information about almost all the actions inside the browser.